# Processing in .NET of unmanaged native exception/crash

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, unmanaged

I have a .NET application which calls unmanaged method periodically in separate thread (every 5 seconds). And this method crashes sometimes. I need to process this situation somehow. The main problem is I cannot change c++ unmanaged code.

I tried different ways to handle this exception, but without any success:

1. usual

   try {} 
       catch (Exception ex) 
       {}

and

```
try {} catch {}
```

2
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

3   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException;

4.
 Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;

In any case it just crashes silently.

Logically this thread should be restarted, but I know that Thread.Abort() is a bad practice. What is the best practice for such situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, are the ways you've tried? Why can't you just wrap the offending code in a `try/catch`?

Comment: try/catch did not help. also I've tried: 1. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException; 2. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException; 3. Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;

Comment: Edit your question to add the things you've tried. In particular show the try/catch you attempted and explain why it didn't work. Did it crash silently or throw some other exception?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the error is in the C++ code? Is it possible that you're passing it a reference to an array that isn't pinned in memory? That can cause the C++ code to crash if the array is moved during garbage collection.

Comment: Jim, done. I've edited question. It crashes silently.

Comment: Jim, yes. It always works fine for one environment configuration and always does not work for another.

Comment: So what's different about the two environments?

Comment: it described in details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561000/issue-with-requesting-data-via-bidiinterface-with-wi-fi-printer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If unmanaged code crashes your process, you're out of luck. There is no exception propagated to managed code. The only way to be stable against such a crash is to start the unmanaged code in a wholy separate process, not just a thread. You can than use inter-process communication to exchange data as needed, and restart the process if it crashes.

Also, `Thread.Abort` is not only a bad practice - it also will not help you at all while the thread is inside the unmanaged code, such as when the unmanaged code "hangs". `Thread.Abort` will only be allowed to abort the thread as it exits back to managed code.

Comment: `There is no exception propagated to managed code.` I learn something new every day. :)

Comment: Are you certain that you can't solve this with a separate app domain rather than a separate process?

Comment: @JimMischel Sadly, yes. Unless something changed in the latest versions of .NET, unmanaged "crash" brings the whole process to a halt. `AppDomain` is only a managed construct - it doesn't affect unmanaged code; it's great for loading plugins, but it doesn't help with unmanaged code at all. That also applies to unsafe code, reflection and P/Invokes - so don't give your plugins full trust if you're concerned about safety :) This is also the reason why Chrome and others run in so many processes - without exceptions, there's no recovery option without lots of work; restarting a process is easy.

Comment: Luaan, thanks for your answer. I've tride 2 ways to make it using different processes, but without luck yet: 1) start another console application which write to standard output and redirect this output using ProcessStartInfo. So I can grab the output, but if child process crashes, user will receive notification. User does not see this notification if I set CreateNoWindow property [of ProcessStartInfo] to true. But in this case I can't grab the output. 2) AnonymousPipeServerStream + AnonymousPipeClientStream - nearly the same.

Comment: Also I would like to try WCF or windows service. Which process model is more suitable in my case? Thanks.

Comment: Windows services are usually used like daemons - waiting (or running) in background all the time. That doesn't sound like what you want. As for the console application variant, you need to set `UseShellExecute` to `false` too. And of course, you would want to watch for process exit, and if it happens without an "OK" message, you've got a failure. If that isn't good enough, there's still a ton of other options for IPC on Windows, a quick Google search will help you a lot.